# How do you configure Lucene in Sitecore to only index the latest version of an item on the master db?

Tags: c#, search, lucene, indexing, sitecore

I recognise this is a moot point on the web database, so this question applies to the master db...

I have a custom index set up in Sitecore 6.4.1 as follows:

```xml
<index id="search_content_US" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">_search_content_US</param>
    <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <search_content_home type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler, Sitecore.Kernel">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/usa home</Root>
            <Tags>home content</Tags>
        </search_content_home>
    </locations>
</index>
```

I query the index like this (I am using techphoria414's `SortableIndexSearchContext` from this answer: [How to sort/filter using the new Sitecore.Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314195/how-to-sort-filter-using-the-new-sitecore-search-api)):

```c#
private SearchHits GetSearchResults(SortableIndexSearchContext searchContext, string searchTerm)
    {
        CombinedQuery query = new CombinedQuery();
        query.Add(new FullTextQuery(searchTerm), QueryOccurance.Must);
        return searchContext.Search(query, Sort.RELEVANCE);
    }

...

SearchHits hits = GetSearchResults(searchContext, searchTerm);
```

`hits` is a collection of search hits from my index. When I iterate through `hits` I can see that there are many duplicates of the same items in Sitecore, 1 per version of the item.

I then do the following to get a `SearchResultCollection`:

```c#
SearchResultCollection results = hits.FetchResults(0, hits.Length);
```

This combines all of the duplicates into a single `SearchResult` object. This object represents 1 version of a particular item, and has a property called `SubResults` which is a collection of `SearchResult`s that represent all of the other item versions.

Here's my problem:

The version of the item represented by the `SearchResult` is **NOT** the current published version of the item! It appears to be a randomly selected version (whichever the search method hit first in the index). The latest version **is** included in the `SubResults` collection, however.

E.g.:

```c#
SearchResult
 |
 |- Version 8 // main result
 ...
 |- SubResults
      |
      |- Version 9 // latest version
      |- Version 3
      |- Version 5
      ... // all versions in random order
```

**How do I prevent this from happening on the master db? Either by preventing Lucene from indexing old versions of items, or by doing some manipulation of the result set to get the latest version from the `SubResults`?**

As an aside, why does Lucene bother to index old versions of items anyway? Surely this is pointless for searching content on your website as the old versions are not visible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can implement a custom crawler that overrides the following:

```
public class IndexCrawler : DatabaseCrawler
{
    protected override void IndexVersion(Item item, Item latestVersion, Sitecore.Search.IndexUpdateContext context)
    {
        if (item.Versions.Count > 0 && item.Version.Number != latestVersion.Version.Number)
            return;

        base.IndexVersion(item, latestVersion, context);
    }
}
```

This ensures that only the latest version of an item gets into your Index, and therefore will be the only item pull out of said index

You would need to update your configuration file to set the correct type for the index of course

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - this looks like just the thing. I haven't had chance to implement it yet, but when I do I'll mark this as the answer if it works out.

Comment: Fancy seeing you here, Mr. Burgess. This answer just helped me out :)

Answer (score 8):

In **Sitecore 7** a field **_latestversion** was added to the index, containing a '1' for the latest version (other versions have empty value).

Comment: This is great news! Shame we are not on Sitecore 7 yet, but it's very useful to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

If you let Lucene search in your Web database instead of the Master, it should only index the last published version.

```
<Database>web</Database>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Martijn, that's good news for our live site I guess, but do you know of a way to get this to work on our master db? We need the functionality locally for testing purposes and for our content editors. We have a CM and a CD server.

Comment: Hi @theyetiman, right now I don't have an out-of-the-box solution, I should dig into it. I will see if I have time for it...

Comment: Just wanted to add that the `web` database only ever has the latest version of an item (as long as you aren't directly working in that database). Publishing won't version items, just apply the latest publishable version

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution provided by theyetiman, by using an adjusted sort mechanism, is an interesting approach, it does not provide a perfect solution when the Lucene result scores for the two versions tend to differ. E.g. out of v1 with score 0.7, and v2 with score 0.5, his solution will still return the first version of the item. (At least in my tests.)

After some more digging, the most obvious solution apparently lies in implementing your own `Sitecore.Pipelines.Search.SearchSystemIndex` and using that one instead of the default. If you decompile that code using ILSpy or similar, you will notice the following at the bottom of the `Process` method:

```
foreach (SearchResult current in searchHits.FetchResults(0, searchHits.Length)){
  // ...
}
```

Each such `SearchResult` is actually group-by, where the first result that was returned from Lucene (thus the one with the highest score) is the main result. Hits on other versions (and also other languages) of the same item are accessible through the `Subresults` property of each instance; or `null` when there are none.

Depending on your requirements, you can adjust this part of the class to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Rian. This looks pretty interesting, but I think @Andrew Burgess' answer is probably easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I haven't figured out the exact answer (to stop Lucene indexing old versions on the **master db**) I have come up with an acceptable work-around...

When Lucene returns its results from the index, each `hit` has a field called `"_id"` which is formatted something like this (3 versions of the same item, where the last number is the version):

```
"CCB75380-4E9A-4921-99EC-65E532E330FF%en%1"
"CCB75380-4E9A-4921-99EC-65E532E330FF%en%2"
"CCB75380-4E9A-4921-99EC-65E532E330FF%en%3"
...
```

I'm currently sorting by `Sort.RELEVANCE` which is the default. This is fine if we only had one version of an item in the index, but with several almost identical versions, they all have the same relevance score and Lucene just churns them out in any order. Sitecore then takes the first instance of the item version (even if it's old).

The solution is to specify a secondary sort field. In the `searchContext.Search()` method, you can pass a custom `Sort` object.

```
searchContext.Search(query, new Sort(...));
```

By sorting by Lucene's built in `Sort.RELEVANCE` first, and **then** by the `id` field (descending) in the index, I can ensure that the first `hit` that Sitecore sees will be the latest version and not just a random one:

```
searchContext.Search(query, new Sort
                            (
                                new SortField[2] 
                                {
                                    SortField.FIELD_SCORE, // equivalent to Sort.RELEVANCE
                                    new SortField("_id",SortField.STRING, true) // sort by _id, descending
                                }
                            )
);
```

The `SortField` parameters are as follows:

```
SortField(string fieldName, int type, bool reverse)
```

**This approach has fixed my problem, but if anyone can actually find out how to only index the latest version, please answer!**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out an alternate solution from the above answers,

Architecturally speaking, I think the ideal solution for this problem would be to filter out the older version results using custom code at higher level rather than removing them from the master database index altogether. you don't want to manage the way sitecore is designed to work to solve problem at hand.

Use below predicate to filter out the olderversions and retrieve only latest version

```
predicate.And(item=>item[Sitecore.ContentSearch.BuiltinFields.LatestVersion].Equals("1"));
```

Hope this helps someone !