# Sitecore Content search multiple versions of same document

Tags: search, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am working with Sitecore 7.2 content search, In the content tree, when I edit and approve an item, I get a new version but in the web database is only the latest version stored. When I do a search through the LINQ API, I get multiple versions, I have also tried the IndexViewer utility that also shows multiple versions.

If I go to the control panel and rebuild index then everything works fine. I don't want to go back to control panel every time and rebuild index, Is there anything I can do to control multiple versions of the same document appearing in search?

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- write a custom `DatabaseCrawler` that will make sure to only store the latest version of each item;
- or add a search condition to your query, checking that `_latestversion` equals to `1`.

See this question for further information: [How do you configure Lucene in Sitecore to only index the latest version of an item on the master db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701856/how-do-you-configure-lucene-in-sitecore-to-only-index-the-latest-version-of-an-i)

Comment: _latestversion is always 1 for all search returned item.

Comment: it did a trick in my case. _latestversion field was present and equal to true only on the latest version of each item

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following article from the Sitecore knowledge base. I'm not 100% sure but the symptoms sound similar and the article says that the issue occurs in v7.2 Update-4 (rev. 150408) and up.

Issues with the OnPublishEndAsync index update strategy - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/992608

> "Obsolete item versions may persist in search indexes after publishing. This would result in search indexes becoming out of sync with the actual website content."

Good luck!